# Not finding git merges history locally

Tags: git, merge

I'm working with the following git branches hierarchy :

- Master

  - Develop

    - Feature_A
    - Feature_B

Typically, I'm working on feature branches, and merging changes onto `Develop` when I'm ready. I did:

```
git checkout Develop
git merge Feature_A
```

and that worked. Problem is I messed up Develop and want to revert. So I did this :

```
git revert -m1 a6c457f9a5abd4126a40f2e72b572fd2b91197a7
error: mainline was specified but commit a6c457f9a5abd4126a40f2e72b572fd2b91197a7 is not a merge.
fatal: revert failed
```

But when I look at the git logs, I get this:

```
git log
commit a6c457f9a5abd4126a40f2e72b572fd2b91197a7 (HEAD -> develop)
Author: omartin <...>
Date:   Mon Apr 20 10:58:46 2020 -0400
```

So then I tried looking at the git logs for merges and I see this:

```
jet:~/proj/inferencing$ git log --merges
commit 2b81b8f0e18e9dcf5ff35993b1bbcfb5594d3f8b
Merge: b152a1b 0dc5a54
Author: ...
Date:   Mon Mar 16 23:44:24 2020 -0400

    Merge pull request #1 from omartin2010/async-video

    Async video

commit 5d3cc4172700ad5b2887a73968a379198536cd5d
Merge: 8f328cb 28f3f49
Author: ...
Date:   Fri Feb 28 11:00:26 2020 -0500

    Merge branch 'master' of github.com:...
```

Question is, why, if I'm doing almost daily merges onto the Develop branch, does my `git log --merges` not show these? As a result I wasn't able to do `git revert -m 1 <commit id>`.

Comment: `a6c457f9a5abd4126a40f2e72b572fd2b91197a7` is a commit, but it is not a merge commit. `2b81b8f0e18e9dcf5ff35993b1bbcfb5594d3f8b` is a commit that is a merge commit. What command did you run that you expected to produce a merge commit (probably `git merge`) and what arguments did you provide it and what state did the commit graph have at that time?

Comment: Assuming you did `git checkout Develop; git merge Feature_A`, the remaining question is: what did the commit graph look like, when viewed from the then-current positions of `Develop` and `Feature_A`? Chances are that `Feature_A` was strictly ahead of `Develop` so that Git was able to do a fast-foward instead of merging.

Comment: thanks @torek, I did run `git merge Feature_A`. Actual branch names are different but other than that this was the command. I'm not a git expert, I'll try to look at the graph from a vscode plugin. But yes, it was strictly ahead of Develop. I'm the only person working on this project and at the same time I'm trying (dangerously at times) to learn git's more advanced things. So if it did fast-forward, how would I normally revert?

Comment: After a fast-forward, you can undo the effect with a `git reset`. You need to find the correct commit hash ID; it's normally in the reflog for the branch, as long as you haven't let it expire (30 days or more).

Comment: Thanks @torek - that's how I ended up fixing this. I had unfortunately lost a bit of code but it was less efforts to rewrite than to find exact way to backtrack after the few changes/attempts I made trying to fix this.

Comment: Note that you can, if you choose (for any purpose of your own), force Git to make a real merge instead of doing a fast-forward not-really-a-merge operation, by running `git merge --no-ff` instead of just `git merge`. If Git already has to do a real merge, the `--no-ff` option does nothing, but if Git could do a fast-forward instead, this prevents the fast-forward.